# How can I apply a transparent background to the windowBackground

Tags: android, view, background

I have created a simple image using Inkscape with a transparent background, alpha(0) and at the center, I have a small logo. I then applied it to my styles like below:

```
<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/loginHeaderBackground</item>
</style>
```

It works fine, however, I'm missing my main objective, its displaying a black screen with the middle icon instead of a transparent one.

**What I want** (User should be able to still see their phone background when the app starts to launch)

[image]

**What I'm getting**

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: can you post an image of what you want vs what you have?

Comment: edited the post

Answer (score 0):

There is an example for you. I wrote custom theme and i added this theme to my activty. You should add this your splash activity in manifest file.

```
<activity ... 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.TranslucentTheme"
 .../>
```

styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="TranslucentTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_black</item>
    </style>

    <color name="transparent_black">#DA000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: In my case, I want a transparent background with an icon at the middle